# Trouble updating UI using Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

I am working on a plugin based WPF Application. The plugins are loaded parallely using multiple threads. One of the plugins is a UI plugin that uses a WPF RibbonWindow. I am trying to add a RibbonTab from Plugin A to the UI plugin.

Since the calling thread does not own the RibbonWindow, I am using the Dispatcher.Invoke on the RibbonWindow. Unfortunately the code inside the delegate is never being called. The application is still responsive, but the tab is not being added.

Is there anyway I can access the UI thread from another plugin? 
Can I have a thread that can be kept alive all through my application, for me to use that Thread for operating on the RibbonWindow?

```
 System.Threading.ThreadStart start = delegate()
        {
            log.Debug(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,  (ThreadStart)delegate() {
                    log.Debug(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    ribbonRoot.Items.Add(myRibbonTab);
                });
            }
            else {
                log.Debug("We have access add directly.");
            }

        };

        new Thread(start).Start();
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add the ribbon tab you don't need to start a thread for it (you are already dispatching it to the UI thread) unless there is more you want to do on the thread. Even then it might be better to use the `ThreadPool` instead of creating a new thread. Any way, in scenarios like this I usually pass the `Dispatcher` from the main window to the plugin via the plugin interface instead of directly accessing the `Application.Current.Dispatcher`. Makes it more encapsulated and you have better control over it in unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I am getting a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.` exception. I tried creating the ribbonwindow using the dispatcher and that made the application non-responsive. Please advise.

Comment: I had to create each ribbontab using the Application.Current.Dispatcher and that solved my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to invoke it on the UI thread.

btw: Why are you casting to ThreadStart? (not important, just curious)